# Extended display not working for Lenovo Thinkcentre (Intel Xeon)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, intel

I've recently purchased a second-hand Lenovo Think Centre M73 to use as my linux workstation. Everything was going fantastic until I tried hooking up my second monitor. The ThinkCentre has 1 VGA port and 1 DisplayPort, yet Ubuntu will not recognize both inputs simultaneously. That is, if the DisplayPort is connected, Ubuntu will show on that monitor ONLY when booted. If I disconnect the DisplayPort and leave the VGA connected, then it shows on the second monitor. But I cannot get it display on both monitors simultaneously.

Here's the result of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I wonder if this some kind of issue with the Intel drivers. Additionally, I notice that even though Ubuntu doesn't "recognize" the second monitor, that if I unplug its VGA connection from the ThinkCentre, the sleeping monitor will wake-up. Any thoughts on how to fix this? It's a fresh install of 20.04 LTS Desktop and I was really looking forward to the extended display setup.

Edit: results of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

and `uname -r`

```
5.8.0-44-generic
```

Comment: To try the default kernel, you could boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop installation media and use the "Try Ubuntu" option (not 20.04.2 media) but sorry you'll likely need to wait for others who have some experience with issues such as yours; I'd only be guessing.  *the UNCLAIMED is your issue, which makes me think kernel module (driver) but you're better with someone who's used your chipset*

Comment: @guiverc your idea is bringing me much closer to the answer. It turns out the extended display isn't working because I had nomodeset in my grub config. Now, if I remove this, by setting to "", then reboot, both monitors work. Yet then none of programs work.... Any ideas would be super helpful if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel integrated graphics drivers are usually installed automatically when they're found, as they're part of the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package, but you can confirm they're in place by trying to install the package again:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Install the drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
   ```

   ***Note:** You may see a message like "xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version". If you do, then carry on to the next step.*
2. If the driver is installed but Ubuntu can't see it, you may need the `mesa-utils` package as well:

   ```
   sudo apt install mesa-utils
   ```
3. Reboot
4. Confirm the `UNCLAIMED` message is gone:

   ```
   sudo lshw -C display
   ```

So long as the video device is properly loaded — and the total resolution of both displays does not exceed the maximum for the video card — then you should be able to extend your desktop across both displays

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this unfortunately didn't work - both mesa-utils and xserver-xorg-video-intel were already installed to the most recent versions. The display is still unclaimed and the dual monitor setup not working.